# TypeError writing dictionary to csv in Python

Tags: file, csv, dictionary, python-3.x

I've got a question concerning the csv-module in python. I just can't seem to write a list of dictionaries to a csv file. It would be fantastic if you could help me spot the mistake in here.

I get a TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found

```
f = open("datadump.csv", 'wt')
try:
    fieldnames = ['type', 'name', 'contact', 'address', 'tel', 'web', 'infos']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';', extrasaction='raise')
    writer.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))
    for entry in listd:
        writer.writerow(entry)
finally:
    f.close()
```

listd is a list of dictionary objects, a typical one of which looks like this:

```
{'web': '', 'tel': 'Tel.: 043 377 97 32', 'name': ' Kinderkrippe Doppelchnopf', 'contact': '', 'address': 'Rütistrasse 37d, 8134 Adliswil', 'infos': '', 'type': 'kita'}
```

Comment: Just in case... one of your example dicts has `'Tel.: 043 377 97 32'` which is just a string and not a valid key/value. That's not actual data is it?

Comment: @kobejohn: That's the value for the 'tel' key, right? It might be strange to include the name of the key in the value, but it doesn't invalidate the dictionary.

Comment: indeed. poor reading skills for the lose. sorry about that.

Comment: @user1460682:Try including a `print entry` in the for loop. Maybe that helps to identify the problem.

Comment: You can use `writer.writeheader()` to write the first row of your csv file. As for your code, I see no reason for it not to work, the problem is probably the `listd`.

Comment: @Jan Did you ever get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code basically unmodified works for me. I think maybe you have something strange with `listd`. Try the full code below.

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['type', 'name', 'contact', 'address', 'tel', 'web', 'infos']
data_item = {'web': '', 'tel': 'Tel.: 043 377 97 32', 'name': ' Kinderkrippe Doppelchnopf', 'contact': '', 'address': 'Rtistrasse 37d, 8134 Adliswil', 'infos': '', 'type': 'kita'}
listd = [data_item]*3
f = open("datadump.csv", 'wt')
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';', extrasaction='raise')
try:
    writer.writerow({fn:fn for fn in fieldnames})
    for entry in listd:
        writer.writerow(entry)
finally:
    f.close()
```